# Angular 7 Environment

Tags: angular, angular7

Hola estoy intentando usar environment para poder iniciar angular en varios modos.

Pero me sale un error, aqui esta el codigo:

angular.json

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            }
          ]
        },
        "test": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    ...

   "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
        },
        "test": {
          "browserTarget": "frontend:build:test"
        }
      }
    },
```

enviroment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
};
```

enviroment.test.ts

```
export const environment = {
 production: false,
 test: true,
 url: 'google.com'
};
```

dashboard.ts

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

console.log(environment.url)
```

Pero me sale este error:

> La propiedad 'url' no existe en el tipo '{ production: boolean; }'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos los entornos de ejecución (*environments*) declarados en tu proyecto deben tener un fichero environment.<entorno>.ts asociado, con los valores propios del entorno necesarios para adaptar la aplicación a estos.

Todos estos ficheros deben, además, tener **exactamente** la misma estructura.

El error que tienes es debido a que el objeto `environment` del fichero `environment.ts` (el entorno por defecto para desarrollo, sin nombre), no tiene los mismos atributos que `environment.test.ts` y que (espero que lo tengas, aunque no lo hayas nombrado) `environment.prod.ts`. Añade una propiedad `url` con un valor de tipo `string` a estos archivos y funcionará.